# Feature class error in Feature compare (Data Management) analysis

Tags: feature-class, data-management

I have some troubles on performing a feature compare data analysis.
I created a new feature layer with different point variables, see picture. The two different colored points are from two different data sets (1982) and (2014). The attribute tables contain similar variables and my idea is to be able to test the validity of the smaller data set (2014) compared to the (1982) data set on certain parameters to use the more extensive data that it contains.
However, when I perform the feature class analysis it gives a 'feature class extents are different' error.
Within the attribute table, the field names are similar (soil characteristics such as LUTUM, M50 etc). (not in similar order though) However, within the 'Omit_Field' the parameters are different according to the original layer that they are from: 'bhorizont9999.LUTUM' and 'bhorizont5159.LUTUM' for example. I thought that this might be an indicator of that the field names should be changed. Also, it might be due to a different spatial reference?

My main question is really if you think that this is the correct analysis and how I can make sure that I compare the paired profiles that are 'grouped' in the picture.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem of extends i have resolved like this:

First check if both features are in same coordinate system. 
If the coordinate system is same, create a geo-database and import both features inside it.
Inside of geo-database create a Feature Dataset choosing same Coordinate of features.
Import both features inside dataset, that try to apply "Feature Compare".

Maybe it will work,